# How to enable **Loopback IPv6** in Apache 2.2.11 Webserver?

Tags: apache, ipv6

I am using Apache webserver 2.2.11.At present i am able to browse my website using IPv4 loopback address.Instead of this IPv4 loopback address(127.0.0.1) i need to use IPv6 loopback address(::1) to browse the website.I have already tried to add this address in httpd.config

```
Listen [::1]:80
```

But apache server didn't start after this change due to the configuration error.

Comment: That config line works for me. It is not a syntax error. What error are you getting?

Comment: "The configuration error" - what configuration error?

Comment: [crit] (OS 11004)The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.  : alloc_listener: failed to set up sockaddr for [::1]
Syntax error on line 54 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Sec/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
Listen setup failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by installing the latest Apache(2.4) web server.And add the line **Listen [::1]:80** in the configuration file( httpd.conf)